# Переменная через UTF-8

Tags: php, кодировка

У нас есть переменная $text = "Тру-ля-ля"; как эту переменную перевести в UTF-8 . Я имею ввиду, чтоб текст этой переменной стал в UTF-8. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

```
iconv("какая-там-ваша-исходная-кодировка", "UTF-8", $text)
```